# In angular2 how can I import Router Segment so I can use getParam function

Tags: angular

In angular2 how can I import Router Segment so I can use getParam function

I'm using the latest angular2 libraries

**Current ts code for this:**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Router, ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'BlogArticleComponent',  
  templateUrl: 'blogArticle.component.html'
})

export class BlogArticleComponent {
  router : Router;
  jobSlug: string;


  constructor(router: Router, route: ActivatedRoute){   
      this.router = _router;

      this.jobSlug: = route.params.map(p => p.slug);
      console.log(this.jobSlug);//undefined currently
  }
```

**This is the code I need to get working:**

> this.jobSlug: = route.params.map(p => p.slug);

Comment: You normally get route parameters by injecting ActivatedRoute: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/ActivatedRoute-interface.html

Comment: @JBNizet Ive updated my current attempt above

Comment: Get rid of the semi-colon `this.jobSlug:`. And you still need to subscribe to to the params.